# Can anyone give me a little explanatory example about InsertOnSubmit and InsertAllOnSubmit

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to understand difference between those two and really need a explanatory simple example for them.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`InsertOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx) adds a single record. [`InsertAllOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.itable.insertallonsubmit.aspx) does the same, but for a set (`IEnumerable<T>`) of records. That's about it.

Comment: I think to clarify, what that means is that if you have a collection of items to submit, you would pass it to "InsertAllOnSubmit", instead of iterating over the collection and calling "InsertOnSubmit" on each item.

Comment: Thanks :) I was a little bit confused but it's nice example to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Theres a [good Q&A](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2747627&SiteID=1) about this on the MSDN forums. Most interesting bit:

> InsertAllOnSubmit() simply loops over
>   all the elements in the IEnumerable
>   collection and calls InsertOnSubmit()
>   for each element.

Answer (score 1):

I found this example of InsertAllOnSubmit() at the very bottom of [this page](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET02).  Just remember to add a using statement for System.Collections.Generic

```
// Create list with new employees
List<Employee> employeesToAdd = new List<Employee>();

employeesToAdd.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeID = 1000, FirstName = "Jan", LastName = "Jansen", Country = "BE" });
employeesToAdd.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeID = 1001, FirstName = "Piet", LastName = "Pieters", Country = "BE" });
employeesToAdd.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeID = 1002, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Johnson", Country = "BE" });

// Add all employees to the Employees entityset 
dc.Employees.InsertAllOnSubmit(employeesToAdd);

// Apply changes to database
dc.SubmitChanges();
```